# *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R terminated

Tags: r

Using Ubuntu-12.04,R-2.15.2

I put command on R prompt `as.Date("2013-04-12")` & gets error as below,

even I tried to install a package `R CMD INSTALL twitteR_1.1.4.tar.gz`,got error

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7fa9b2de7807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109700)[0x7fa9b2de6700]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10ba1a)[0x7fa9b2de8a1a]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(+0x97149)[0x7fa9b3350149]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(+0x9921a)[0x7fa9b335221a]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(+0xd7b7e)[0x7fa9b3390b7e]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x17a)[0x7fa9b339b9fa]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_applyClosure+0x340)[0x7fa9b33a0210]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(+0xdec04)[0x7fa9b3397c04]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x17a)[0x7fa9b339b9fa]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_applyClosure+0x340)[0x7fa9b33a0210]
/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so(+0xdec04)[0x7fa9b3397c04]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why R shows this error,when I am installing any new package? before this,it was not showing any error. Also as.Date() function not working now,but its working in other machine having same configuration

Comment: You may have broken / corrupted your installation. Your report is still close to meaningless as it is incomplete. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example